# Which side to do the PWM in a H-Bridge, High side or Low side?

Tags: pwm, h-bridge

as the title sugests, I am wondering, is there a better side to do the PWM? I believe the high side is better, because the current will flow through the lower part diodes in the Off cicle, which means, the H-Bridge TVSs will help the MOSFETs diodes with the current circulation.
Is there something else I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you want your current to flow in an H-bridge if you don't control all the switches? Please add a schematic.

Comment: @SzymonBęczkowski of course I control all the switches...arent you familiar with the H-Bridge circuit?[check it here](http://robots.freehostia.com/SpeedControl/SpeedControllersBody.html)
Besides there are the flyback diodes for current circulation

Comment: No answers? No one? :/

Comment: or if your h-bridge has an enable line, is that a better place to do the pwm?

Comment: @Rob Starling, no, the disable line will make all the outputs go tristate (high Z...all open...coast...call it as you like it), the PWM input will do the go-brake which is better than go-coast for the induced current circulation.

Comment: @mFeinstein ah! thx.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the low side is better because the required N-channel transistors are cheaper and faster than similar P-channel transistors. Switching speed is what you need for PWM; if switching is slow, the transistors will dissipate more energy.

*Unless the datasheet states otherwise*, don't rely on the internal diodes in a MOSFET. They are not designed for use as flyback diodes.

Comment: All my MOSFETs are N-Channel, this is not related to be in the High side or in the Low side...so I am sorry, but this doesnt answer the question..